# How to access Java array list data from another class

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I'm trying to make a quiz in Java but I'm having trouble accessing the array list data from the tester class and therefore my question text isn't showing up. I have three classes; tester, quiz interface and quiz set up. I've been playing around with it for a while and I'm pretty sure I'm starting to make things worse so I thought I'd post on here.

The questions are added to the array list in the Tester file but I can't seem to access this in the set up class for this method:

```
public void setQuestion(int randIndex) {
    qi.getQuText().setText(getQuestionList().get(randIndex).getQuestionText());
}
```

Expected output was to take a random question from the array list and display the question text but instead nothing appears and it is blank.

I'm fairly new to Java and programming so any detailed answers are welcome! Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuizTester {
    private static ArrayList<Question> questions; //declares arrayList to holds the questions

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            QuizSetUp theQuiz = new QuizSetUp();
            questions = new ArrayList<Question>(); //constructor

            questions.add(new FillInBlank("____________ is the ability of an object to take many forms.", "Polymorphism"));
            questions.add(new FillInBlank("The process where one object acquires the properties of another is called __________", "inheritance"));
            questions.add(new FillInBlank("The ___________ keyword is used by classes to inherit from interfaces", "implements"));
            questions.add(new MultipleChoice("Which programming technique can be used to prevent code and data from being randomly accessed by other code defined outside the class?",
                            "Polymorphism", "Encapsulation", "Inheritance", "Construction", "Encapsulation"));
            theQuiz.pickQuestion();


    }
    public ArrayList<Question> getQuestionList() {
            return this.questions;
    }


}
```

////////////////////////quiz set up file.

```
public class QuizSetUp {
    private QuizInterface qi;
    private QuizTester test;
    //private ArrayList<Question> questions; //declares arrayList to holds the questions
    private int counter = 1;
    Random random;
    int randIndex;

    public QuizSetUp() {
            setInterface();
            //questions = new ArrayList<Question>(); //constructor
    }
    private enum QuAnswer { CORRECT,INCORRECT }

    public void setInterface() {
            qi = new QuizInterface();
            test = new QuizTester();

            //add action listeners to each of the buttons
            ActionListener cl = new ClickListener();
            qi.getNextBtn().addActionListener(cl);
            qi.getStartQuizBtn().addActionListener(cl);

            //allows users to press enter to start quiz rather than having to click quiz button
    KeyListener ent = new KeyBoardListener();
    qi.getUName().addKeyListener(ent);
    qi.getUPassword().addKeyListener(ent);

    }



    public void pickQuestion() {
            randQuestion();
            setQuestion(randIndex);
            //setAnswer("A", randIndex);
            //setAnswer("B", randIndex);
            //setAnswer("C", randIndex);
            //setAnswer("D", randIndex);
            //setCorrectAnswer(randIndex);
            //qi.resetTimer();

    }

    public void setQuestion(int randIndex) {
            qi.getQuText().setText(getQuestionList().get(randIndex).getQuestionText());
    }

    public void setNextQuestion() {
            //qi.getTimer().cancel();
            //qi.cancelInterval();
            if (counter < 5) { //users must answer five questions to complete quiz
                    pickQuestion();
            } else {
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(qi.getPanels(), "End of quiz");
                    //switch to end panel to show results of quiz
            }
    }

    public int randQuestion() {
            random = new Random();
            randIndex = random.nextInt(questions.size());
            return randIndex;
    }

    //inner listener class for buttons
    private class ClickListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    if (evt.getSource() == qi.getStartQuizBtn()) {
                            qi.setEnteredName(qi.getUName().getText());
                            qi.setEnteredPass(qi.getUPassword().getPassword());
                            validateInput();
                    } else if (evt.getSource() == qi.getNextBtn()) {
                            counter++;
                            if (counter == 5) {
                                    qi.getNextBtn().setText("Finish Quiz"); //changes next button text on final question
                            }
                            if (counter < 6) {
                                    qi.getQuProgress().setText(counter + " of 5");
                            } else {
                                    //shuffle to end panel
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    //inner listener class for key presses
    private class KeyBoardListener implements KeyListener {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                            qi.setEnteredName(qi.getUName().getText());
                            qi.setEnteredPass(qi.getUPassword().getPassword());
                            validateInput();
                    }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    }

    //method to validate input by user to log in
    public void validateInput() {
            //presence check on username
            if (qi.getEnteredName().length() > 0) {
                    //presence check on password
                    if (qi.getEnteredPass().length > 0) {
                            //ensures password is at least 6 char long
                            if(qi.getEnteredPass().length > 5) {
                                    qi.getCards().next(qi.getPanels()); //getPanels() == cardPanel
                            } else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                                    "Your password must be at least six characters long.",
                                                    "Password Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                            }
                    } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                            "Your did not enter a password.",
                                            "Password Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
            } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "You did not enter a username. Please try again.",
                                    "Username Violation", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: can you post your code here it self ? I won't click some random links to help you out :)

Comment: Additionally, a more detailed problem description, the expected and the actual behavior, would also help.

Comment: one tip in advance: if I were you I wouldn't pipe so many method calls in one statement. Get the `QuestionList`-entry first, then get its text and print it out with `System.out.println(..)`. That way you can see if you can get the text in the first time. Only then I would set this text to `qi`. But even there I would create a new method `qi.setQuText()` so you don't have to call `qi.getQuText()` first. In short: more lines of code are easier to debug :)

Comment: Thanks GameDroids. I tried putting a print statement and the output from the array list was null. So I'm guessing I'm not accessing the array list that I added questions to but an empty one. Still unsure how to access it :(

Comment: well, I am still not sure where the error is but maybe you could try passing the `questions` list another way, maybe with a method in your `QuizSetUp` class `setQuestions(ArrayList questions){this.questions = questions;}` that way you have the questionslist directly in your `QuizSetUp` class and it will be easier to access it (without a static list in you `QuizTester` class)

Answer (score 1):

After some alterations, I was able to get your code running. But I have to warn you, there are quite some changes:

- `QuizTester` now only has a `main` method to start the program. It will initialize and fill the list with questions and then pass it to the `QuizSetUp` instance
- I didn't have your `Question` class, so I reduced it to an `ArrayList<String>` (just to make sure, that the questions could be passed)
- And I didn't hvae your `QuizInterface` class so I helped myself with a small implementation that would simply print out the question when a new question gets set

**QuizInterface** (small helper class)

```
public class QuizInterface {

    private String text;

    public QuizInterface() {
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        System.out.println("question text = "+this.text);  // this is just to make sure it worked
    }
}
```

**QuizSetUp** (heavily reduced)

```
public class QuizSetUp {

    private QuizInterface qi;
    private ArrayList<String> questions; // uncommented, it's needed now
    private int counter = 1;
    Random random;
    int randIndex;

    // I chose to pass the list with the constructor but the setQuestions() will do as well
    public QuizSetUp(ArrayList<String> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
        setInterface();
    }

    // NEW method – but it's not needed
    public ArrayList<String> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    // NEW method – but it's not needed
    public void setQuestions(ArrayList<String> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    private enum QuAnswer {
        CORRECT, INCORRECT
    }

    public void setInterface() {
        qi = new QuizInterface();
//        test = new QuizTester();   // this is no longer needed since QuizTester is only used to start the program
    }

    public void pickQuestion() {
        randQuestion();
        setQuestion();   // randIndex is already a global variable in this class, no need to pass with the method call
    }

    public void setQuestion() {
        // QuizInterface has a new method now called "setText()"
        // so here we access the list "questions" (it is already initialized, because we pass it to this class when constructing it)
        // this.randIndex is global, so we can use it directly in this method as an index to the questions list (as you already did it)
        qi.setText(this.questions.get(this.randIndex));
    }

    public void setNextQuestion() {
        //qi.getTimer().cancel();
        //qi.cancelInterval();
        if (counter < 5) { //users must answer five questions to complete quiz
            pickQuestion();
        } else {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(qi.getPanels(), "End of quiz");
            //switch to end panel to show results of quiz
        }
    }

    public int randQuestion() {
        random = new Random();
        randIndex = random.nextInt(questions.size());
        return randIndex;
    }
 // .... the rest I left out here because it is not needed for this little test
}
```

**QuizTester** (only needs the main method)

```
public class QuizTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>(); //as you can see I replaced the List with a list of Strings (because I didn't have your Question class)

        // so these are only strings... 
        questions.add("____________ is the ability of an object to take many forms.");
        questions.add("The process where one object acquires the properties of another is called __________");
        questions.add("The ___________ keyword is used by classes to inherit from interfaces");
        questions.add("Which programming technique can be used to prevent code and data from being randomly accessed by other code defined outside the class?");

        // here I create the QuizSetUp instance and pass the list right with the constructor
        QuizSetUp theQuiz = new QuizSetUp(questions);
        // if everything works out, calling this method 
        // should pick a new question, set it to the QuizInterface
        // and the QuizInterface (the helper version I made) will print it out
        theQuiz.pickQuestion(); 
    }
}
```

Those three classes can compile as they are and when I ran the program I got this output

```
question text = The ___________ keyword is used by classes to inherit from interfaces
```

I know this is a lot different from what you have, the only **big** change I did was passing the newly create questions list directly to the `QuizSetUp` instance – so no accessing any static lists.

Comment: While I admire your effort, I wonder if spending so much time fixing "dogs breakfast" code is really in anyone's interest.

Comment: yeah, you are probably right – especially when the *error* is so small. next time I will think twice before jumping right on the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line:

```
qi.getQuText().setText(getQuestionList().get(randIndex).getQuestionText());
```

where is the `getQuestionList()` implemented?  It looks like a method call, except that `QuizSetUp` doesn't declare a `getQuestionList()` method.  It is in a different class.

Conclusion: the code that you've shown us in the question won't even compile.

---

I should point that this (in `QuezSetup`) is very bad style, dnd liable to cause confusion.

```
private static ArrayList<Question> questions;

public ArrayList<Question> getQuestionList() {
        return this.questions;
}
```

While `this.questions` *looks* like it is referring to an instance variable, it is actually referring to a static variable.  The `this` is misleading.

Comment: No, the only main method is in the Tester class. I could email you all of the classes in the project if you have the time to take a look for me? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: No can do.  Sorry.  You need to learn how to debug your own code ... and the best way to learn debugging is to do it.